# AJAX request failing to be recognized as POST by PHP script

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, forms

I am trying to post a form to a PHP script, and it is getting stuck at validating the request as a POST request, and thus it exits from the PHP script. The AJAX request returns as successful, but the data returned from the database says the recognition of the request as POST failed. I've tried changing the content types etc, to no avail.

JS:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $("#delete4").on('click', function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var ok = confirm('Are you sure you want to delete this?');
        if (ok == true)
        {
            console.log("true")
            var data = $("#form4").serialize();
            $.ajax({
                     data: data,
                     type: "post",
                     url: "delete_AJAX.php",
                     success: function(data) {
                        console.log("successfully deleted");
                        console.log(data);
                        //$("#div4").remove();
                     },
                     error: function(data) {
                          alert("fail");
                          console.log(data);
                      }
            });
        } else {
            return;
        }
    }); 
});
```

HTML:

```
<form type="text" name="form4" id="form4" action="delete_AJAX.php" method="post">
    <div class="aligner">
        <button type="button" class="button_div" name="edit" onclick="send(52)">Edit</button>
        <button type="button" class="button_div" id="delete4">Delete</button>
        <button type="button" class="button_div" name="read" onclick="send2(52, 13)">See</button>
    </div><br>
    <input type="hidden" id="hidden_c4" value="13" name="hidden_c">
    <input type="hidden" id="hidden_bid4" name="hidden_bid" value="52">
</form>
```

PHP:

```
require_once("db.php");
if ($_REQUEST['REQUEST_METHOD'] === 'POST')
{

    $bid = $_POST['hidden_bid'];
    echo "passed request";

    $sql = "SELECT * FROM xxx WHERE yyy = $bid";
    $result = mysqli_query($connection, $sql);
    if ($result === false)
    {
        die("f1");
    }
    $resultCheck = mysqli_num_rows($result);
    if (!resultCheck > 0)
    {
        echo "ERROR NO RESULT";
        exit();
    };
    $row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);
    $delete_cover = $row['cover'];
    unlink($delete_cover);



    // updating table row
    $sql2 = "DELETE FROM xxx WHERE (yyy=?);";
                $stmt = mysqli_stmt_init($connection);
                if (!mysqli_stmt_prepare($stmt, $sql2))
                {
                    header("Location: ../create.php?error&prepare1111");
                    exit();
                }
                else
                { 
                    $stmt->bind_param("i", $bid);
                    mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);
                    mysqli_stmt_close($stmt);
                    $connection->close();
                    echo "successfully deleted";
                }

} else {
    echo "FAILURE TO REQUEST";
}
```

So I keep consistently getting failure "FAILURE TO REQUEST", and when I remove any barrier to the script, post is shown as empty, and the variables arent set. Thus it stops at the "f1" error. Any help would be amazing!! Thankyou!

Comment: no idea, why are u using $_REQUEST when you know your method is POST, i know this is not an issue here. first of all check browser console for your param

Comment: second use `print_r($_REQUEST)` use this before `if ($_REQUEST['REQUEST_METHOD'] === 'POST')
`

Comment: You are using the wrong variable: It should be `if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] === 'POST')`.

Comment: **TYPO** `if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] === 'POST')` Look in the right place

Comment: Oh that  works, I thought the problem wouldn't lie there because if I got rid of the if statement, it still wouldn't go through. But SERVER works great! thank you so much :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You seem to be using the wrong global variable for the "REQUEST_METHOD".
Instead of `$_REQUEST['REQUEST_METHOD']` use `$_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']`

Answer (score 2):

In the conditional,

`$_REQUEST['REQUEST_METHOD']` should be replaced with `$_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']`.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe could this help

```
if( $_POST ) {
    echo 'posted';
    //do some stuff
}
```

Comment: An explanation would be nice, but this would also solve the OP's problem.